# Spivak Calculus Chapter 8 "Least Upper Bounds", Problem 3a

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

The solution manual to Spivak's Calculus has typos sometimes, and other times the solutions are terse. I'd say the solution to the following problem is at least terse.

> 3a) The proof of Theorem 7-1 showed that there is a smallest $x$ in
> $[a,b]$ with $f(x)=0$. If there is more than one $x$ in $[a,b]$ with
> $f(x) = 0$, is there necessarily a second smallest? **Show that there
> is a largest $x$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(x)=0$. (Try to give an easy proof
> by considering a new function closely related to $f$.**

Here is Theorem 7-1:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a) <0 < f(b)$, then there is
> some number $x$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0$.

I am interested in the question posed in bold above. I believe I proved the desired result using a longer proof that mirrored one that was present in the main text. The "easy proof by considering a new function..." presented below is still incomprehensible to me. Here it is verbatim:

> Since $b-a+x$ varies between $b$ and $a$ as $x$ varies between $a$ and
> $b$, the function $g(x)=f(b+a-x)$ satisfies $g(a) = f(b)>0$ and
> $g(b)=f(a)<0$. So there is a smallest $y$ with $g(y)=0$. Then
> $x=b-a+y$ is the largest $x$ with $f(x)=0$.

Can someone provide a better explanation for how this proof works, or perhaps a more verbose version of this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my approach,let $x=b+t(a-b)$ where $t\in[0,1]$ so that $x\in[a,b]$ also.Then let $g(t)=f(b+t(a-b))$,we have $g(0)=f(b)>0$ and $g(1)=f(a)<0.$Since $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$,there is a smallest $t_{0}$ with $g(t_{0})=0.$Therefore $x=b+t_{0}(a-b)$ is the largest $x$ with $f(x)=0.$